# Making money off ads, but can't even see the ads

Tags: android, ads

I am currently in a strange situation. I have implemented ads onto my app correctly, but cannot see them when I run my app on the beta version of it, but when I check my admob account I seem to be generating revenue. Im not sure what is going on. Does anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Generating revenue, so you released the App to the wild?

Comment: No it is still in beta

Comment: Do you have other Apps generating Ad revenue? I am not sure how you are getting revenue, when you cannot even click on the Ad to generate it.

Comment: I have no other apps. Maybe its from testing, but still the ads never showed up when i was testing it.

Comment: This sounds like a win-win situation. I wish Youtube would copy what you have going here...

Comment: I am so confused lol, is this illegal